# How to select specific column from multiple table in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two table's table as follows:

**Names** :-

id firstname lastname, address, phone

Now, i have another table which contains lets say location data for person's in first table

**Location** :-

id latitude, longitude

now , i have to **select, firstname, latitude, longitude** only using sql/sqlite query.

Currently, my query is :-

```
  Names nameTable INNER JOIN Location locationTable ON nameTable .id =locationTable .id WHERE nameTable .id=12
```

This query i use in android sqlite and it returns me full table.

I want specific columns only to increase performance. Can anyone help me with the query ?

Comment: `SELECT Names INNER JOIN Location ON Names.id = Locations.id WHERE Names.id = 12` should work, if id is **UNIQUE**.

Answer (score 4):

This select statement should work:

```
SELECT n.firstname, l.latitude, l.longitude FROM Names n JOIN Location l ON n.id = l.id WHERE n.id=12
```

I usually use [SQLLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) (or something similar) which allows you to load your database and to execute SQL queries on it. This way you can test your statements befor putting them unto you code.

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem please accept the answer! Thank you very much